# Will lazy function pass through the argument at once when the argument is a list?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Say you have an immutable list of numbers `xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and a function **doubleMe** which multiplies every element by 2 and then returns a new list.

When we call `doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(xs)))`, how will the lazy function works?

```
doubleMe([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) -> doubleMe(doubleMe([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])) -> doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])))
```

or

```
doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(1))) -> doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(2))) -> ... -> doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(8)))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant in the second context?

Comment: Well, actually I have another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907117/how-does-lazy-evaluation-works-when-the-argument-is-a-list) related to this question. And it should run on the second way. But I don't know why.

Comment: How is `doubleMe` implemented?

Comment: I don't have its implementation. It is simply stated in a haskell tutorial, just like what I put in my question.

Comment: `1` is not a list (without some odd and unusual code lying around), so you certainly won't see `doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(1)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `doubleMe` is lazily implemented, it is evaluated like this:

```
doubleMe (doubleMe (1:2:3:[]))
= doubleMe (2 : doubleMe (2:3:[]))
= 4 : doubleMe (doubleMe (2:3:[]))
= 4 : doubleMe (4 : doubleMe (3:[]))
= 4 : 8 : doubleMe (doubleMe (3:[]))
= 4 : 8 : doubleMe (6 : doubleMe [])
= 4 : 8 : 12 : doubleMe (doubleMe [])
= 4 : 8 : 12 : doubleMe []
= 4 : 8 : 12 : []
```

With three nested calls, instead of two, the evaluation is analogous.

Essentially, the evaluation strategy finds the *outermost* `doubleMe` call which has an argument in weak head normal form -- i.e., either `[]` or of the form `x : xs`. Then it applies the definition:

```
doubleMe [] => []
doubleMe (x:xs) => (2*x) : doubleMe xs
```